# Google App Engine not displaying .png files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a basic landing page through the Google App Engine using the plugins in Eclipse.

I've looked through loads of posts on here but cannot get this working with any of the solutions. I've got a folder of .png images (/bg)that are supposed to show as the background of my site. I have another folder of .png files (/icons) for icons and these seem to show without issue. Both these folders live in the /img folder. I've got .png files listed in the appengine-web.xml file but still can't get it working.

```
<static-files>
   <include path="**" />
   <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
   <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />
   <include path="/**.png" expiration="120d"/>
   <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
   <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
</static-files>
```

I've adjusted and changed the image names so many times now thinking it might be a file length/format issue. Nothing seems to make a difference. When I download the app from Google after deploying it the entire folder just seems to have disappeared (or never got uploaded). I've tried so many combinations I'm not sure where to go from here

Everything runs locally from Eclipse / jetty server without issue.

The file names look like this: bg1at1024.png

It's driving me batty and I'd love some help.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the contents of your war file before uploading? It might be that maven (or whatever you're using) does not include this folder in the first place.